# How can I convert below mysql query to laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
      FROM (
            (SELECT 1 AS orderField,
                mem.`fname`,
                mem.`lname`,
                mem.`profilenam`,
                mem.`mem_id`,
                mem.`photo`,
                mem.`ethnicity`,
                mem.`profile_type`,
                mem.`gender`,
                mem.`verified`,
                mem.`deleted`
           FROM members AS mem
           INNER JOIN network AS net ON net.frd_id = mem.mem_id
           WHERE net.mem_id= '1728'
           AND (mem.`profilenam` LIKE '%abc%'
                OR lname LIKE 'abc%'
                OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE 'abc%')
         )
        UNION
        (SELECT 2 AS orderField,
                `fname`,
                `lname`,
                `profilenam`,
                `mem_id`,
                `photo`,
                `ethnicity`,
                `profile_type`,
                `gender`,
                `verified`,
                `deleted`
         FROM `members`
         WHERE (`profilenam` LIKE '%abc%'
                OR lname LIKE 'abc%'
                OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE 'abc%')
       )
     ) AS t
     WHERE t.verified='Y'
     AND t.`mem_id` NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,1728)
     AND t.`deleted`='N'
     GROUP BY t.mem_id
     ORDER BY t.orderField,t.profilenam DESC 0,50

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ( (SELECT 1 AS orderField, mem.fname, mem.lname, mem.profilenam, mem.mem_id, mem.photo, mem.ethnicity, mem.profile_type, mem.gender, mem.verified, mem.deleted FROM members AS mem INNER JOIN network AS net ON net.frd_id = mem.mem_id WHERE net.mem_id= '1728' AND (mem.profilenam LIKE '%abc%' OR lname LIKE 'abc%' OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE 'abc%') ) UNION (SELECT 2 AS orderField,  fname,  lname,  profilenam,  mem_id,  photo, ethnicity,  profile_type,  gender,  verified,  deleted FROM members WHERE (profilenam LIKE '%abc%' OR lname LIKE 'abc%' OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE 'abc%') ) ) AS t WHERE t.verified='Y' AND t.mem_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,1728) AND t.deleted='N' GROUP BY t.mem_id ORDER BY t.orderField,t.profilenam DESC 0,50");
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution